# How to stop spring framework logs in the spring integration application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a requirement to stop framework logs. I need the application logs to be printed not framework logs.We are using spring boot and spring integration for our application and wire trap to logs the request. I can change the logging level(logging.level.org.springframework=WARN) to stop the framework logs but when i do that my application logs are also not printed. Is there any way i can stop the framework logs to be printed.

```
<int:channel id="arrowEyeRequest">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="arrowEyeTransformedRequestLogger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="arrowEyeTransformedRequestLogger" expression="'ArrowEye(FP-024)---- transformed ArrowEye request---- \n'.concat(payload)" level="INFO" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<int:logging-channel-adapter>` has a `logger-name` attribute:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="logger-name" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Provide a name for the logger. This is useful when there are multiple logging Channel Adapters configured,
                and you would like to differentiate them within the actual log. By default the logger name will be the
                fully qualified class name of the LoggingHandler implementation.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

So, even if you have `logging.level.org.springframework=WARN`, you still can configure something like `logging.level.myLogger=INFO` and have that in the channel adapter:

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="arrowEyeTransformedRequestLogger" 
               expression="'ArrowEye(FP-024)---- transformed ArrowEye request---- \n'.concat(payload)" 
               logger-name="myLogger"
               level="INFO" />
```